# How do you become a vampire/werewolf in Elder Scrolls Online

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

The game is released for a few days now. I have heard that you can turn into thoses beasts. I have a few questions about that

- How do you turn into werewolf/vampire ? On the chat people said they can bite others but who bite them first?
- How long does the effect last ?
- Are there any cons ? Maybe if your are a vampire you take damage from the sun like in older Elder Scrolls ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both Vampires and Werewolves (PvE) will spawn in high-level areas, and their attacks have some chance of infecting you with the relevant disease. Once infected, you will have a new quest that you must complete to either become the monster you wish to be, or be cured of the disease.

You can not be infected by the Vampire disease if you are currently infected with the Werewolf one, and vice versa.

**Vampirism Effects** *([more details](http://elderscrollsonline.info/vampire))*

You'll unlock a new skill line you can make use of, you'll also start to have these effects at various stages, until you feed on a human opponent (PC or NPC), which will reset it to "stage 0".

- Up to 30 mins:

  - 50% Fire Damage Weakness
- 30 to 60 mins:

  - -25% Health Regeneration
  - +50% Fire Damage Weakness
  - -20% Health Cost to Vampirism Skills
- 60 to 90 mins:

  - -50% Health Regeneration
  - +50% Fire Damage Weakness
  - -40% Health Cost to Vampirism Skills
- More than 90 mins:

  - -75% Health Regeneration
  - +50% Fire Damage Weakness
  - -60% Health Cost to Vampirism Skills

**Werewolf Effects** *([more details](http://elderscrollsonline.info/guides/werewolf))*

You gain access to a skill, ***Werewolf Transformation*** that does pretty much what it says on the tin. While transformed, you'll have access to a new line of skills to unleash your inner puppy, and there are some ill effects of course -- such as a passive ability that increases damage taken from abilities in Fighters Guild skill line, +50% to all poison damage.

**PvP Infection**

Players can also infect other players with their condition.

For Werewolves, the skill *Bloodmoon* can be used once every seven days, acting as a rate-limit. For Vampires, the equivalent skill is called *Blood Ritual*. You have to use these skills at the ritual sites, so it's unlikely you could be turned against your will. Both require level 6 in the respective skill trees.

Comment: Both lines are mutually exclusive. If you're infected by one thing, you're automatically immune to the other. Just keep in mind that Werewolves got their own downsides, e.g. they'll receive additional damage from most Fighter's Guild abilities (with a passive).