# If you finish vampire quest and turn into vampire, can you go back?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

This question is my follow-up to this one : [How do you become a vampire/werewolf in Elder Scrolls Online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/163433/how-do-you-become-a-vampire-werewolf-in-elder-scrolls-online)

If you get vampire disease and do not cure it, is there a way back?

I mean - lets say, you get to lvl 50, you are vampire, but for whatever reason, decide, it is not a good choice and the character is unplayable for you. Can you then cure vampirism and become a regular person, ditching all the effort and skill points put into vampire  skills?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a small fee (well, ~600 Gold), one Prelate Sabinus found at the back of the Mages Guild in the city of Evermore will cure you of your condition.

Comment: Yes but to what faction does that town belong to? How do other factions do it?

Comment: @Odif It belongs to Daggerfall faction. There may be similar purveyors of cures in other Mages guilds, but I can't find any mention of them.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. Could you also update the answer to include that bit of information too?

Comment: for the ebonheart pact it is riften.

Answer (score 2):

For Aldmeri Dominion you want Prelate Sabinus in Rawl'kha, in Reaper's March at the back of the Mages Guild in the temple. She cures both Vampiries and Werewolves.